# Omitting "who is" in "I would like to date a girl [who is] at least of my intellect"

Tags: relative-clauses, ellipsis

Instead of

> I would like to date a girl **who is** at least of my intellect.

can I say

> I would like to date a girl at least of my intellect.

by dropping the phrase "who is"? What I try to mean is:

> I would like to date a girl whose intellect level is at least the same as mine.

Answer (score 3):

In colloquial English the phrase would be *I would like to date a girl **at least as smart as me***.  That would mean that you're willing to date girls who are smarter than you as well.  You just don't want to be smarter than the girl is.

But you could also say **who is my intellectual equal** or **who is my equal in intelligence** if you're looking for equality there.

Comment: Thanks. What about these two: "I would like to date a girl who is at least of my intellect" and "I would like to date a girl at least of my intellect"? These sentences are also correct and they have the same meaning, right?

Comment: No, **of my intellect** is not idiomatic; it doesn't mean "on my intellectual level".

Comment: Would they sound wrong? Wouldn't any native English speakers say them? Should I say "I would like to date a girl at least of my level of intellect" instead, by using the word "level"?

Comment: It would not sound right.  The girl would be **at** your intellectual level, not **of** your level.

Comment: @ Tᴚoɯɐuo Acccording to the people in wordreference forum, I can use "of" there.

Comment: What did they say exactly? And was the answer from a native speaker?

Answer (score 1):

It's fine to drop the "who is" in that sentence, but the resulting phrase *"a girl at least of my intellect"* is clumsy.  Possibly better:

> I want to date a girl **having/with** an intellect at least equal to mine.

Still, the more idiomatic expression is "intellectual equal" or, if you must, "of equal intellect":

> I want to date a girl **of** (at least) **equal intellect**.
>
> I want to date (at least) my **intellectual equal**.

Comment: Thanks. Is the first version "I would like to date a girl who is at least of my intellect" clumsy as well to you?

Comment: @DereMemo  Yes, "of my intellect" is the problem.  "My intellectual equal" sounds better.

Comment: Thanks. But I have found instances where the authors used "of my intelligence" on Google Books. For example: https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=5FMRNNJPTWwC&pg=PA334&lpg=PA334&dq=%22a+person+of+my+intelligence%22&source=bl&ots=iAQ1ODtBVx&sig=vrUsExTEG0d05Mb47AAGnfFNmcY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMl6j_lsbaAhVJr6QKHTHdDxwQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22a%20person%20of%20my%20intelligence%22&f=false

Comment: One of the other sentences on Google Books is this: "It was inexcusable for a person of my intelligence to act like that, he said." So, If we can say these, can't we also say "I would like to date a girl at least of my intellect"?

Comment: @DereMemo  i didn't say you *can't* say it.  I just said it was clumsy.

Comment: Do you think there are any Native English speakers who don't find it clumsy?

Comment: @DereMemo  Who can say?  The real question is why you want to force this phrase.   You've already been told this is a rude way to express your preference, but on top of that, you want to express it in a way that sounds unnatural?  I'm not sure how I can help you with this goal.